# Trying to merge three different bar charts into one with chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to have 3 different categories into one bar chart, but I just can't get it to work. I'm using chart.js with React.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Here's what I tried:

```
function VerticalBarChart({data,width,height}) {
  const data= {
    labels: ['Department',"Gender","Age"],    
    datasets:[
        {
            label: "Corporate",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [3]
        },
        {
            label: "Warehouse",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [10]
        },
        {
            label: "Finance",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [6]
        },
        {
            label: ["Male","Female","Other"],
            backgroundColor: "red",
            data: [0,7,5]
        },
        {
            label: ["18-29","30-49","50+"],
            backgroundColor: "black",
            data: [0,10,4]
        }

    ],
    options:{
        responsive:true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        labels:{
            fontColor: 'black',
            fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
               ticks:{
                beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                 }
            }]
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
};
    return (
        <div>
            <Bar data={data} width={width} height={height} options={data.options} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Which gives me this result:
[image: What I'm getting with this code]

If I do it like this, it creates additional spacing for the different categories. I'm trying to figure out how to arrange the data variable so that chart.js knows its separate categories and it's not tied to each other. Basically I'm trying to combine three different bar charts together in one.